# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Build

Tags: debugging, msbuild, object-reference

I am trying to build a project using Visual Studio 2019 and C# but it fails.

CSC : error SI0001: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

There is not any specific info and I do not know where to look at. I will appreciate some help.
PS: I did not change anything in this project and it works for my colleague.

thank you in advance

Output:

```
Build started...
BuildEvents_OnBuildBegin --12:42:40 PM
1>------ Build started: Project: [ProjectName], Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>CSC : error SI0001: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
1>warning CS0108: ....
1>warning CS0108: ....
1>warning CS0108: ...
1>warning CS0108: ...
1>warning CS0108: ...
1>warning CS0108: ...
1>Done building project "ProjectName.csproj" -- FAILED.
BuildEvents_OnBuildProjConfigDone Start --12:42:42 PM
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
BuildEvents_OnBuildDone --12:42:42 PM
```

Comment: Any build log or `csproj` file?

Comment: @mu88 Nothing. But I added output result to my post. there are some warnings but there is no explanation about the error

Comment: Did you increase the log verbosity? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2022

Comment: Errors and warnings from the C# compiler start with 'CS'. I don't recognize the 'SI' prefix and a web search doesn't turn up anything for 'SI0001'. Do you have analyzers or other tools configured as part of the project?